# cakePHP- PieChart Helper class

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-helper

I am trying to make use of this [Helper class](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rloaderro/2008/01/14/cake-meet-pie), which was written for earlier version of cake.. It seems that it makes use of the vendor() method to use a third party class, but now that method  is deprecated. I am trying to use the following in the helper class to include the third party class called eq_pie.class.php:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'eq_pie' );
```

I placed the third party class in the app/vendor folder(which im not sure if its correct)
The helper class makes use of it like so

```
    //vendor('class_eq_pie'); Now commented out.. 

    $this->eq_pie = new eq_pie; //generates error
```

I get this error: `Error: Class 'eq_pie' not found` , which means that the third party class is not being included.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Fellow cakePHP new users... make sure to follow your version's of `cake conventions`.. the problem was that my current `version(2x)` expects class names and their respective files to be `camelCased` rather than `underscored`..

From`eq_pie`, I changed the class name to `EqPieClass`, and file to`EqPieClass.php`. Reference doc here : [Class Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#file-and-classname-conventions) if you run into trouble. Best of luck